# Image is not loading to Image control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am inserting dynamic image control inside a gridview at a specific cell,i can see the image control during run time but image is not getting load.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl= "http://openclipart.org/people/ricardomaia/glossy_red_button.svg";
e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(img);
```

Comment: @Ajay-No Luck, i tried saving the image on desktop too but its it not laoding.

Comment: Code looks fine, please post the HTML got from your browser. Maybe you have to set an ID for img

Comment: plz add your entire code, where are you binding data to gridview?